# compare different id's in a select foreach to show the correct options

Tags: php, html, laravel, input

So i have a html form in the registration where you see the Extra Option exa_name from the 'Extra' table, the price from the Extra table, and a select from the Extraoptions table that connects to the Extra table.

The problem:
The selects (i use a foreach) show all the rows in the Extraoptions->eos_name, and i want it to show the eos_name's where eos_extra_id is the same as the exa_id!

**html form:**
this is what i have now, im not sure how i can compare the eos_extra_id and exa_id in the option value

```
//options(exa_name from the Extra table)
<label>Options</label><br>
                        @foreach($options as $option)   
                            <div>                   
                                <input type="checkbox" class="option" id="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" name="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" value="{{ $option->exa_id }}" {{ isset($cache) ? (isset($cache['option_' . $option->exa_id]) ? 'checked' : '')  : (old() ? (old('option_' . $option->exa_id) ? 'checked' : '') : ($registration ? (in_array($registration ->exa_id, $registration_options) ? 'checked' : '') : '')) }} >
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $option->exa_price }}" class="option_price_{{ $option->exa_id }}">
                                <label>{{ $option->exa_name }}</label> <label class="exa_price">  €{{ $option->exa_price }} </label>    
                            </div>

//extra options select
<select name="extraoptions" class="form-control">
                                <option></option>
                                @foreach($extraoptions as $extraoption)
                                    <option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_id }}" 

                                        {{ (exa_id('eos_extra_id') == $extraoption->eos_id ? 'selected' : "") }}>
                                    {{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                       @endforeach
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is this `exa_id` ? why didn't you select the needed options before sending `$extraoptions` to the view ?

Comment: edited my post, i hope that answers your questions!

Comment: so you want the second select to change when the user selects the first one ?

Comment: no, i want the select to show the exa_name, but the eos_extra_id has to be the same as the exa_id. Because now it just shows every extraoption in the eos_name row

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to limit the display of `$extraoptions` to those that have the same `exa_id`. To do this, use a simple `filter()` function in your `@foreach()` call:

```
<label>Options</label><br>
@foreach($options as $option)   
<div>                   
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" id="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" name="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" value="{{ $option->exa_id }}" {{ isset($cache) ? (isset($cache['option_' . $option->exa_id]) ? 'checked' : '')  : (old() ? (old('option_' . $option->exa_id) ? 'checked' : '') : ($registration ? (in_array($registration ->exa_id, $registration_options) ? 'checked' : '') : '')) }} >
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $option->exa_price }}" class="option_price_{{ $option->exa_id }}">
    <label>{{ $option->exa_name }}</label> <label class="exa_price">  €{{ $option->exa_price }} </label>    
</div>
<select name="extraoptions" class="form-control">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($extraoptions->filter(function($exOpt){ return $exOpt->eos_id == exa_id('eos_extra_id'); }) as $extraoption)
    <option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_id }}">{{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
@endforeach
```

To clarify, I've removed the `selected` logic, as setting `selected` on multiple `<option>` elements inside a single, non-multiple `<select>` isn't going to do much, except show the last matching option as the default selected one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! with $exOpt do you mean $extraoption or $extra?

Comment: Would be `$extraoption`; `$exOpt` is just the variable name for use within the function. I avoided `$extraoption`, as that's the name of each iteration of `$extraoptions`

Comment: i tried your code, and i got an error saying: undefined function exa_id()

Comment: You might have to pass `exa_id` to the function (`function($exOpt) use (exa_id){ ... }` but I don't think that works with functions, and `exa_id` isn't a function in Laravel; that's something you (or a plugin you're using) has defined.